# Difficulty in reducing DE to Kummer form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to reduce a differential equation to Kummer form. I am trying an Ansatz that gets me quite close, but I am running into a difficulty. The form I get is:

$$zf''(z)-2\lambda zf'(z)+(v+z(\lambda^2-u))f(z)=0$$

where $u,v$ are constants, and $\lambda$ a parameter from the Ansatz.

I don't see how I can satisfy both $\lambda=\sqrt{u}$ and simultaneously $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$ to get to the standard Kummer form:

$$zf''(z)+(b-z)f'(z)-af(z)$$

I am new to this, and I am thinking I might choose $\lambda=\sqrt{u}$ and then perform another change of variable, maybe of the form $t=\alpha z$. Would that be a standard "trick" or step at that point? Or is there something else I should try?

Answer (score 1):

Maple gives the solutions to your DE as

$$ f \left( z \right) =c_{{1}}z\;{{ KummerM}\left(-{\frac {-2\,\sqrt {u}+
v}{2\sqrt {u}}},\,2,\,2\,\sqrt {u}z\right)}{{\rm e}^{z \left( -\sqrt {u
}+\lambda \right) }}+c_{{2}}z\;{{ KummerU}\left(-{\frac {-2\,\sqrt {u}
+v}{2\sqrt {u}}},\,2,\,2\,\sqrt {u}z\right)}{{\rm e}^{z \left( -\sqrt {
u}+\lambda \right) }}
$$

Thus if you write $g(x) =  e^{\alpha x} f(\beta x)/x$ for appropriate constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$, you should get Kummer's equation for $g$.

Comment: I was just looking for a continuation with the Ansatz I'm already using ... I actually did change the scale ($t=\alpha z$), and that allowed me to continue and finish. So, to answer my own question, doing a change of scale seemed indeed to be the next reasonable step. But thanks for letting me the full solution, and suggesting another Ansatz.